# How to encrypt a firedac TFDmemTable backup file?

Tags: delphi, encryption, firedac

TFDmemTable has a SaveToFile option including Binary format but if you open the binary file with notepad, you can see all the text. Is their a way to encrypt this file?

Comment: Is this really a Firedac issue? Choose your encryption method and encrypt. Probably by saving to stream, encrypting, and then to file.

Comment: Correct. Not really a firedac issue. How to encrypt a stream and then to file?

Comment: Many different ways to encrypt. Encrypt to a file stream and, well, that's it.